# PHP: variable not working inside of function?

Tags: php, function

```
echo $path; //working
function createList($retval) {
    echo $path; //not working
    print "<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    foreach ($retval as $value) {
            print "<input type='checkbox' name='deletefiles[]' id='$value' value='$value'>$value<br>";
    }
    print "<input class='submit' name='deleteBtn' type='submit' value='Datei(en) löschen'>";
    print "</form>";    
}
```

what am I doing wrong? why is $path printed correctly outside of the `createList` function, but it's not accessible inside the function?

Comment: Where is `$path` defined? Is it defined as `global $path`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Because it's not defined in the function.

There are a few ways to go about this:

**1) Use what Alex said by telling the function it is a global variable:**

```
echo $path; // working

function createList($retval) {
  global $path;

  echo $path; // working
}
```

**2) Define it as a constant:**

```
define(PATH, "/my/test/path"); // You can put this in an include file as well.
  
echo PATH; // working

function createList($retval) {
  echo PATH; // working
}
```

**3) Pass it into the function if it's specific to that function:**

```
echo $path; // working

function createList($retval, $path) {
  echo $path; // working
}
```

Based on how the function really works, one of those will do ya.

Answer (score 10):

If you want it to work, you should use `global $path` in the function, so it looks outside the function scope.

Please note that global variables are sent from hell :).

Answer (score 2):

Cause `$path` inside `createList()` and outside it (in global scope) are two different variables. Read more about [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

you must use the global modifier.

```
echo $path;
function createList($retval) {
    global path;
    echo $path; // works now :)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a global variable, just pass `$path` in.  Of course, if you don't need the variable inside the function, don't bother!

```
echo $path;
function createList($retval, $path) {
    echo $path;
    print "<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    foreach ($retval as $value) {
            print "<input type='checkbox' name='deletefiles[]' id='$value' value='$value'>$value<br>";
    }
    print "<input class='submit' name='deleteBtn' type='submit' value='Datei(en) löschen'>";
    print "</form>";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$GLOBALS['your variable name']` and use it anywhere in your function