# Call to member function on non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function connect(){
$db = new mysqli(localhost, bludevel_PMI, password1, bludevel_PMIForm);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo json_encode(array($mysqli->connect_error));
    return false;
        exit();
}}

function disConnect(){
mysqli_close($db);
}

function downloadData(){
if ($_POST['cmd'] == "downloadData"){

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Jobs");//error on this line
if($result){

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $jobs[$row['PMINumber']] = $row['Address'];
    }
    //$result->close();
        //$db->next_result();
}


$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Installers ORDER BY `Order` ASC");
if($result){

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $installers[] = $row['Names'];
    }
    //$result->close();
        //$db->next_result();
}
echo json_encode(array($jobs, $installers));
return true;

}}
```

I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object`
when i run this script. $db is indeed an object and i've used it successfully in other
functions, so the problem must lie within the function itself. I'm new to php so any 
help is much appreciated.

Comment: Variable scope. It's defined in your connect function, but not passed onto any outside variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: variable not working inside of function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041171/php-variable-not-working-inside-of-function)

Comment: "Disconnect" is spelled "disconnect", not "disConnect". It's not two words.

Comment: You need to put quotes around your strings; relying on your connect line (`(localhost, bludevel_PMI, password1, bludevel_PMIForm);`) to turn your barewords like `localhost` into strings like `"localhost"` is a very bad practice.

Comment: It is indeed a global variable declared at the beginning of the class, and thanx for pointing that out meagar, i will change those although thats not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your `$db` variable is local to the `connect` function. You either need to use a global instance of `$db` (not a good idea) or return the variable from the function, and keep track of it in the calling scope:

```
function connect() {
  $db = new mysqli(localhost, bludevel_PMI, password1, bludevel_PMIForm);
  // ...
  return $db;
} 


function disconnect($db) {
  mysqli_close($db);
}


$db = connect(...);

// Later..

disconnect($db);
```

Comment: the db variable is declared globally and i use it in other function without a problem

Answer (score 0):

As many already pointed out it a scoping issue.

If you want for some reason to stick with global `$db` variable (**which is definitely not the best way to go**) than you should use **[global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)** keyword to explicitly define scope for `$db` in all functions that depend on it, like this:

```
function connect(){
    global $db;
    //your code
}

function downloadData(){
    global $db;
    //your code
}

function disConnect(){
    global $db;
    //your code
}
```

But the better way is to return a $db from `connect()` and pass it to `downloadData()` and `disConnect()`

```
function connect(){
    $db = new mysqli(...);
    ...
    return $db
}

function downloadData($db){
    ...
}

function disConnect($db){
    ...
}

$db = connect();
if (!downloadData($db)) {
    //
}
disConnect($db);
```