# PHP doesn't show correct message

Tags: php

The way I wrote is a bit different from others , I try to store html5 data as global variables in the php files when html5 form is submitted .

I tested my php script by filling up all the forms in the html5 but purposely make username password and confirm password the same . It should show up the exit message under the else {} ; somehow rather it keeps on showing the " PLEase fill in all the fields " . Where is my mistake ? Surely I did something wrong .

I used select for Gender , because if I used a radio tag , and it the user doesn't select a value ( value = "" ) , undefined index error will pops out ..

Here's HTML5

```
                            <p>
                                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="Username" name="Username" type="text" size="20" required />
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" size="20" required />
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" size="20" required />
                            </p>
                            <br />



                            <p>
                                <label for="Name">Display Name</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" size="25" required />
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                <label>Question</label>
                                <br />
                                    <select name="Question" required>
                                        <option value="" selected>Select a question</option>
                                        <option value="What is your mother's full name ?">What is your mother's full name ?</option>
                                        <option value="What is your nickname ?">What is your nickname ?</option>
                                        <option value="What is your first pet's name ?">What is your first pet's name ?</option>
                                        <option value="What is your favourite car ?">What is your favourite car ?</option>
                                        <option value="What is the name of the person you first kissed ?">What is the name of the person you first kissed ?</option>
                                        <option value="What is the name of the teacher who gave you your first failing grade ?">What is the name of the teacher who gave you your first failing grade ?</option>
                                    </select>
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                <label for="Answer">Answer</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="Answer" name="Answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer to your question" size="50" required />
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <br />
                                    <select name="Gender" required>
                                        <option value="" selected>Select a Gender</option>
                                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                    </select>
                            </p>
```

PHP is here

```
 <?php


$Username = $_POST[ "Username" ] ;
$Password = $_POST[ "Password" ] ;
$ConfirmPassword = $_POST[ "ConfirmPassword" ] ;
$Name = $_POST[ "Name" ] ;
$Question = $_POST[ "Question" ] ;
$Answer = $_POST[ "Answer" ] ;
$Gender = $_POST[ "Gender" ] ;


VerifyRegistrationForm() ;


function VerifyRegistrationForm()
{
    if ( empty ( $Username ) == True || empty ( $Password ) == True || empty ( $ConfirmPassword ) == True || empty ( $Name ) == True ||  empty ( $Question ) == True || empty ( $Answer ) == True || empty ( $Gender ) == True )
    {
        exit ( " Please fill in all the fields . " ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( strlen ( $Username ) > 50 )
        {
            exit ( " \" Username \" exceeds maximum length . " ) ;
        }

        if ( strlen ( $Password ) > 50 )
        {
            exit ( " \" Password \" exceeds maximum length . " ) ;
        }

        if ( $Username == $Password )
        {
            exit ( " \" Username \" and \" Password \" must not be the same . " ) ;
        }

        if ( $ConfirmPassword != $Password )
        {
            exit ( " \" Password \" is invalid . " ) ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The function can't see the variables outside of it if you're not declaring them as global. But you should rather hand them over. `function VerifyRegistrationForm($Username, $Password, $ConfirmPassword, $Name, $Question, $Answer, $Gender) {` `VerifyRegistrationForm($Username, $Password, $ConfirmPassword, $Name, $Question, $Answer, $Gender);`

Comment: still you can use radio and default you can set one of two as selected.

Comment: Step 1: put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script. Step 2: Stop using global variables and instead use dependency injection. Google it if you don't know what that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041171/php-variable-not-working-inside-of-function

Comment: So true story what Mike said. Show *all* errors, warnings and notices PHP throws by using `error_reporting(-1)`. It helps you detecting errors or possible faults in the code.  
Also, make sure you put your elements inside a `<form method="POST">` tag.