# PHP: $_POST variables unexistant into functions

Tags: php

I am bringing some info trough $_POST, but when I try to make use of this info into any function, console emerges an error about Undefined Variable (in this example, $ms_img brings an error, as well as $con -the connection query declared on conexionbbdd.php- and any othe variable inside functions.

EDIT: Neither passing as arguments works, it emerges one error per argument as this:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for checkCost(), called in C:\wamp\www...\actions\msg_newMessage.php on line 96 and defined in C:\wamp\www...\actions\msg_newMessage.php on line 17

```
function checkCost($con,$ms_img,$id){...}
```

CODE:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../conexionbbdd.php");
    include("../conexionapi.php");

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];   
    $inclass = $_SESSION['inclass'];   

if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'activo'){

    $ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];
    $ms_img = $_POST['ms_img'];
    $ms_prefix = $_POST['ms_prefix'];
    $ms_phone = $_POST['ms_phone'];


    function checkCost(){
            $totalCost = 0;

            if ($ms_img!=""){
                    $totalCost=2;
            }   

            else{
                    $totalCost=1;
            }

            $checkCredits=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT us_credits FROM ws_users WHERE us_id=$id");

        }


        function sendMessage(){

            //WHATEVER
        }

    if($inclass==='1'){       
        checkCost();        
    }
    else{
        sendMessage();        
    }

}else{

header('location:../login.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to pass the variables as arguments to the function or declare them with `global`.

Comment: **Do not** use `glob` to inject global vars into a funciton. In long term this can result very confusing code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: variable not working inside of function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041171/php-variable-not-working-inside-of-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have access to superglobal variables like $_POST in any function. But global variables such as `$con` that should be initialized in an including file is not accessable in a function. You can pass it as parameter. And **do not** use the `global` keyword to inject global vars into a funciton. In long term this can result very confusing code. So you could  do:

```php
function checkCost($con){
    $ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];
    $ms_img = $_POST['ms_img'];
    $ms_prefix = $_POST['ms_prefix'];
    $ms_phone = $_POST['ms_phone'];

        $totalCost = 0;

        if ($ms_img!=""){
                $totalCost=2;
        }   

        else{
                $totalCost=1;
        }

        $checkCredits=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT us_credits FROM ws_users WHERE us_id=$id");


    }
```

But its still very procedural. I recommend you to start to read [OOP](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.php).

Comment: I do need OOP, that's for sure. But it is still a bit confusing for me. Thank you for your explanation, worked.