# Variables not working in PHP PDO

Tags: php

This is my PHP PDO code:

```
<?php
$number = 1;
function result($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM customerdata';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print " ". $number ."       ". $row['name'] . " <br> "; // this is line 6 

    }
}
result($conn);
?>
```

This is the error, I am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\a.php on line 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: variable not working inside of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041171/php-variable-not-working-inside-of-function)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PDO or MYsql

Answer (score 0):

Pass the number variable as a parameter in the function.  The number variable does not exist in that function.  As said, either pass as a parameter or declare the number variable as a global variable in the function

Answer (score 0):

```
$number
```

is a variable. You should do this

```
function result($conn) {
    insert line   global $number;
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM customerdata';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print " ". $number ."       ". $row['name'] . " <br> "; // this is line 6 

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked. Your answer and Arun's answer do the same thing in all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the number as a arugument to the function

```
 function result($conn,$number) {
     $sql = 'SELECT name FROM customerdata';
        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
            print " ". $number ."       ". $row['name'] . " <br> "; 

        }

    }
```

Comment: Worked. Your answer and Alexios answer do the same thing in all conditions?

Comment: usage global in php is considered to be bad practice check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why.Instead of that pass the variable as parameter to the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use two options here either pass $number as argument or declare it at global

**Sol 1:**

```
<?php
$number = 1;
function result($conn,$number) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM customerdata';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print " ". $number ."       ". $row['name'] . " <br> "; // this is line 6 

    }
}
result($conn,$number);
?>
```

**Sol 2:**

```
<?php
$number = 1;
function result($conn) {
    global $number;
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM customerdata';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print " ". $number ."       ". $row['name'] . " <br> "; // this is line 6 

    }
}
result($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Both do the same thing under all conditions?

Comment: I recommended to use sol1 to pass variable as argument. As global declaration is not good practice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216340/the-advantage-disadvantage-between-global-variables-and-function-parameters-in